# "Configuration error. No migrator configured." when running MigrateUsers

Tags: user-profile, claims

Migrating a SP Server 2019 site to claims and running MigrateUsers($true) fails and puts this in the logs for every user and group.

Configuration error. No migrator configured.    14f7e39e-845f-6002-7dbe-fa871f2660cd
SPUser '13': Could not get migration data for entity so SKIPPING. Check migrator for further logs.

I've set up Active Directory Import and it's importing users but I'm not sure if the configuration is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below piece of code for migrating your web application from Windows to Claims?

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity https://webAppUrl -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissions:$true -Verbose
```

Comment: Tried that. Same error as above in the logs.

Comment: Found out the issue . I got the same issue and on investigating found out that the issue is because of a user profile that no longer exists in Active directory . We deffered a user from AD but the user was present in SharePoint due to the synchronization . So during migration from Windows to claims , SharePoint was giving error for this user profile.